# native parallax effect on top of webview in ios

Tags: ios, webview

We want to implement a native bar on top of a web view and would like to give parallax effect to this native bar.

please details if this native bar parallax works with webview scroll

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). SO is for detailed questions about something you tried yourself first. Please experiment yourself, then come back with your coding issues.

Answer (score 1):

to make parallax effect on the top of webview you can use this [library](https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader)

```
import MXParallaxHeader
```

then add below line in your viewController

```
var scrollView: MXScrollView!
```

and add below line in your `viewDidLoad`

```
        // Parallax Header
        scrollView = MXScrollView()
        scrollView.parallaxHeader.view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("StarshipHeader", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView // You can set the parallax header view from a nib.
        scrollView.parallaxHeader.height = 300
        scrollView.parallaxHeader.mode = MXParallaxHeaderMode.fill
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        webView = UIWebView()
        scrollView.addSubview(webView)
```

then add this in your `viewController`

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        var frame = view.frame

        scrollView.frame = frame
        scrollView.contentSize = frame.size

        frame.size.width = 2
        frame.size.height -= scrollView.parallaxHeader.minimumHeight
        webView.frame = frame

    }
```

Hope this will help you